# What is the best way to log into Gmail using Selenium Webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I use selenium with python to login  to my Gmail with chrome browser, But there was a problem while logging in look to photo .
[look to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhc4H.png)

this is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

EMAIL="your text"

PASS = "your text"

chrom_path ="C:\\development\\chromedriver_win32"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrom_path)

driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#inbox")

email_box= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="identifierId"\]')

email_box.send_keys(EMAIL)

email_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(5)

pass_box= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="password"\]/div\[1\]/div/div\[1\]/input')

pass_box.send_keys(PASS)

pass_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: _But there was a problem_ Post the problem here, in plain text.  Don't make us click on an image.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is because GMAIL identifies the bot(your script) and blocks you from logging in.

To overcome this issue, you can use a python library known as `undetected-chromdriver`. This library has been developed for the same purpose. You just have to install this library and import it in your code as use it as below:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = uc.Chrome()
```

For more info about `undetected-chromedriver` refer the below:

https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/2.1.1/

https://www.zenrows.com/blog/undetected-chromedriver#what-is

https://www.zenrows.com/blog/undetected-chromedriver#conclusion

Answer (score 0):

Gmail blocked you because their site detected a selenium bot.

You can bypass bot-detection by using [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) in `uc` mode.

First `pip install seleniumbase`. Then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
    sb.click('a[data-action="sign in"]')
    sb.type('input[type="email"]', "test123@gmail.com")
    sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
    sb.sleep(5)
    # sb.type('input[type="password"]', PASSWORD)
    # sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
```

(To access the raw `driver` from the script, use `sb.driver`)